# Fire IBAction automatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ibaction

I have a button and want to fire it automatically by itself without touch.
Is it possible?

```
-(IBAction)xxx:(id)sender
```

Comment: Do you want to "fire it" now, just once? Or do you want to "fire it" after some delay, just once? Or do you want to fire it repeatedly? The solution depends on which one you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer assumes you have the method:

```
- (IBAction)someAction:(UIButton *)sender {
}
```

and that you have a reference to the button in an instance variable named `someButton`.

If you just need to "fire it" now, simply call it:

```
[self someAction:someButton];
```

If you need to "fire it" once, but later, you can do:

```
// call it 5 seconds from now
[self performSelector:@selector(someAction:) withObject:someButton afterDelay:5.0];
```

If you want to fire it repeatedly, use a timer:

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(buttonTimerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)buttonTimerFired {
    [self someAction:someButton];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Action can be called like every regular function - you can do it by running a timer on something else.

Comment: can you just give me sample code... i use timer its not working

Comment: Post your timer code and perhaps somebody can find what you are doing wrong with it.

Comment: Take a look: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSTimer` for doing your work.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.01f target: self selector: @selector(BtoonMethod) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];

-(void)BtoonMethod
{
  // write code for call yor button method

}
```

Comment: Why use a timer to call it once just 0.01 seconds from now?